# Tkinter dependancy on Tile for Mac OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, osx-leopard

Hi I'm getting the following error when using python3 on Mac OSX 5:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 107, in <module>
    sv1 = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=vScroll)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/ttk.py", line 1138, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::scrollbar", kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/ttk.py", line 559, in __init__
    _load_tile(master)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/ttk.py", line 47, in _load_tile
    master.tk.eval('package require tile') # TclError may be raised here
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't load file "/Library/Tcl/tile0.6/libtile0.6.dylib": dlopen(/Library/Tcl/tile0.6/libtile0.6.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Tcl/tile0.6/libtile0.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I then ran: `lipo -info /Library/Tcl/tile0.6/libtile0.6.dylib` and got: `Non-fat file: /Library/Tcl/tile0.6/libtile0.6.dylib is architecture: ppc`.

I have an intel mac. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

tile is part of tcl/tk. You have somehow gotten the PowerPC version installed instead of the Intel version.  Update to the correct version. [This page](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/)   gives combinations based on your OS X and python version.